# Writing a script to auto-create new google sheet upon data entry

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have a google sheet that receives data via a form submission from a third party. I'm trying to write a script that creates a new sheet every time a unique UserID is submitted.

For example, If I have 5 submissions where the UserIDs are A,B,B,C,C, I am trying to have the script create a unique sheet for A, B, and C and group duplicate UserID submissions in that sheet. I figure a pivot table filtered for UserID may accomplish the latter half of that but I haven't been able to figure out the sheet creation yet to test it.

So far, this is the code I've been working with:

```
function formSheet(e) {
  var sheetName = e.namedValues['user-id'][0];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
if (!sheet) {
  sheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName);
  var formSheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var headers = formSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, formSheet.getLastColumn());
  headers.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, 1));
}
sheet.appendRow(e.values);
}`
```

For reference, the sheet with the data is titled "submissions", and the data I want is under the header "User-Id" in column 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You used 'user-id' in your script and 'User-Id' in your question so which is it?

```
function formsheet(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid');
  var name=e.namedValues['user-Id'][0];
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  if(shts.indexOf(name)==-1) {
    var sh=ss.insertSheet(name);
    var hdrs=e.range.getSheet().getRange(1,1,1,e.range.getSheet().getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    sh.appendRow(hdrs);
  }else{
      var sh=ss.getSheetByName(name);
  }
  sh.appendRow(e.values)  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I renamed the field "user-name" so as to avoid any confusion about capitalization. I plugged that script in and it told me there's a bad value on line 2. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Did you add the 'ssid'?

Comment: Yeah I have my sheet's SSID from the URL in there. I meant to say the second line of code under the formSheet line where it's trying to retrieve the 'user-name' value is what's giving me the error. The form, sheet, and script all refer to the field as "user-name" so I'm not sure if there's something I'm doing wrong with the SSID I input or if there's an additional command I need to add.

Comment: Add another line to the first line after `function formatSheet(e) { Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));` and the view logs and share that with me.

Comment: I added it to my answer.  Do it that way and the get then submit a form and view logs.  Copy the the logger and let me see it.

Comment: **[19-05-29 22:10:21:918 EDT] Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property "namedValues" from undefined. (line 3, file "Code") [0.14 seconds total runtime]**



                That's the message I have in the execution transcript. Going to view>log just shows an undefined message with a timestamp of my most recent attempt to run the script.

Comment: Please, use the code I gave you and submit a form and go to View/Logs and copy it here so that I can read it.  But it looks like your not getting the Event Object.  By any chances are you trying to run this function from the script editor?  Rather that an onFormSubmit trigger or perhaps you haven't included the 'e' parameter in the function body.

Comment: To test the script I had been running it from the script editor I originally had an onFormSubmit trigger, but since the form is linked from a third party source rather than a google form I have an onEdit trigger set. I copied the code you have in your answer, went to view>log, and it takes me to the apps script dashboard which gives me the same "namedValues" undefined message I pasted above. As I'm sure you can probably tell I'm relatively new to all this and I'm working on this as a side project to help me learn so I really appreciate your help so far.

Comment: You need to read about [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) for different triggers.  They all have their own characteristics and data that they pass.  An onEdit Trigger does not have a namedValues object.  And you can't run this code from the Script Editor unless you supply the Event Object.